# How to searching symbols from Visual Studio Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a C# extension for visual studio code and I'm getting stuck on something. I need to allow the user to select a symbol from the current workspace, then have that selection returned to me.

I basically need exactly what cmd+t does but instead of navigating to the symbol I want it returned to me. I initially wanted to use showQuickPick with the results of executing `vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider` but I cant get `vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider` to return all results. It seems you **have** to provide a filter. As a side question, does anyone know how to execute this with a wildcard perhaps, something like:

`vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider', "*") //this does not work`

Comment: Just found you found solution: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39522 Was that you? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use empty string:

```
let symbols = await commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeWorkspaceSymbolProvider', '');
```